# PHP/jquery - opening a modal on a different page via an anchor

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What is the cleanest way to open a modal window on a completely separate web page using an anchor? Application is using PHP, jquery 1.11.1 and Boostrap 3.1.1.

## Scenario:

I'm building a web application which has a list of geographical territories (the script which lists them is called `territories.php`). Each territory can have multiple offices. These are listed underneath each territory, e.g.

### Territory A

- Office 1
- Office 2
- Office 3

I have another ***separate*** webpage which gives much more information about a territory. This is opened by passing in an 'id' GET parameter. Example `territory.php?id=14` assuming 'Territory A' had the ID 14. This script, `territory.php` has a Bootstrap modal window and some jquery/ajax to open a view for editing details of each office.

## Goal:

I'd like to make some links on `territories.php` so when you click 'Office 1', 'Office 2' or 'Office 3' it will take you to the page with the appropriate modal open.

My plan was to create links such as `territory.php?id=14&office=1` and then use logic in `territory.php` to check if there is an 'office' GET parameter and run the jquery function to open the modal and do the ajax call to get the appropriate details.

My question though is if that's the cleanest way to do it? I don't like adding lots of things as GET parameters in URL's as it looks very messy, in my opinion. Can this be achieved using POST requests or any better/alternative methods?

Any feedback would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using POST but if page gets refresh then it will open an additional popup requesting to resubmit the POST data. Another way to do this is save `office=1` flag in session. Read the session on next page and save it in a temporary variable, open the popup/modal based on temporary variable and delete the session.